# Stuck creating nested drop down navigation menu

Tags: html, css

Attempting to make a drop down navigation bar using CSS and HTML. I can't get the nested list to dis-attach from the Navigation fixed bar.

I followed [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar), but I'm beginning to get lost in the code. Just need someone to look over my code. I feel I'm not structuring my code correctly. I notice people on online youtube videos using things like `li a, .dropbtn` I don't understand the breakdown of this. The html/css book I read said that you can apply CSS to multiple sections of HTML by adding them with a space, for example `html body {margin: 0;}`. I'm just lost at this point

```css
* {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* vertical alignement */
  align-items: center;
  /* how you want horizontal distribution */
  /* space-evenly | space-around | space-between */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.printing {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2F4F4F;
}

.printing>li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}



.flex-container {
    display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 100px;
}
 
.flex-container > div {
   text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
    
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
 .column {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="main.html">
        <img src="Images/Navigation/Full Intak Logo-01.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="printing">Printing</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
      <li>Banners</li>
      <li>A-Frame</li>
      <li>Menu Boards</li>
      <li>Takeout Menus</li>
      <li>Business Cards</li>
      <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
      <li>Posters</li>
      <li>Books</li>
      <li>Envelopes</li>
      <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
      <li>Flyers</li>
      <li>Letterheads</li>
      <li>Brochures</li>
      <li>Vinyl</li>
      <li>NCR Forms</li>
      <li>Catalogues</li>

    </ul>
    <li class="item">Graphic Design</li>
    <li class="item">Chinese Calendars</li>
    <li class="item">FAQS</li>
    <li class="item">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>

<div class="flex-container"

<div><img src="Images/Printing/Dinner Menus-01.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Banners" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Posters" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Poster" /></div> 

</div>
</body>
```

I expect it to create a secondary nav below the current fixed nav bar, but it just creates a list next to the tab I want to drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not looking too bad! The basic idea is you have to `display: none` your sub-menu, then on hover of the parent, display it :-)

I've amended your code slightly below to show you what I mean.

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.item.has-children:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="main.html">
        <img src="Images/Navigation/Full Intak Logo-01.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item has-children">Printing
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
        <li>Banners</li>
        <li>A-Frame</li>
        <li>Menu Boards</li>
        <li>Takeout Menus</li>
        <li>Business Cards</li>
        <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
        <li>Posters</li>
        <li>Books</li>
        <li>Envelopes</li>
        <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Brochures</li>
        <li>Vinyl</li>
        <li>NCR Forms</li>
        <li>Catalogues</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">Graphic Design</li>
    <li class="item">Chinese Calendars</li>
    <li class="item">FAQS</li>
    <li class="item">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your code alone works perfect, but when I adjusted my file, it still doesn't work. I added the rest of the code that I didn't add. Can you spot anything wrong that's corrupting the navigation?

Comment: Did you make sure you changed everything that I did in my code? Can you update your question with your current code so that I might be able to help you? Also. just a side note - you should always try to run your code through a checker/validator (like, https://validator.w3.org/) to make sure you don't have any fundamental errors :-)

Comment: I updated the code. you'll see the incorrectly formatted parts in CSS are the extra ones. I'm not sure why when I post code it gets so spaced out. Mainly the containers for the content below the nav. I'll use validator as well now and see what the heck I've done LOL

Comment: @Yabusa Ok, I've updated my answer and cut out everything that you absolutely don't 'need' to make it function. So you need to make sure you've included all the above CSS. Also, you need to put the `.sub-menu` `ul` inside the parent `li` (like I have done) - and you're missing a closing tag `>` on your `flex-container` in your HTML :-)

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. When I create a new file and put your code, it works. When I add your code to mine, it doesn't work. I tried using the validator, only spacing issues arise. Do you think the flex containers are interfering?

Comment: Can you try pasting my code into your IDE and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You possibly misunderstood something in your book. Using the space will narrow down your selection instead of choosing multiple elements, as you're specifying the descendants.

When you use space, you mean the element to the right contained within the element on the left. In your case

```
html body
```

means you are targeting element *body* within the element *html*.

If you used the following selector:

```
.class1 .class2
```

it would address all the elements with class class2 inside of the elements with class1.
On the other hand, comma is used only to separate multiple selectors, meaning that for

```
html, body
```

the CSS properties will address both - the html and the body. Just like in the example

```
.class1, .class2
```

the CSS properties will be added to all elements with class1 and/or class2, regardless of their parents.

Comment: It's not just that. There are loads.

Comment: I agree and I meant it more as an explanation than a solution to the answer. You won't get far if you don't understand the basic concepts of CSS combinators.

Comment: That extremely helped, you have no idea. I was so confused thinking > behaved like a comma, but the space is like a >. You were right, I misread that section. Really appreciate the clarification

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would ever tell you is, don't follow W3Schools! No! Coming to what you have done...

```css
html body {
```

I strongly believe you wanna have:

```css
html, body {
```

The comma above matters a lot.

Next thing is, hide the submenu initially. This can be done using `display: none;` applied to the right selector, assuming, you have got a `<ul>` inside a dropping down `<li>`.

```css
li ul {display: none;}
```

So talking about the above stuff, that's where you went wrong. A `<ul>` cannot have anything other than `<li>` inside it as a direct child. You have another `<ul>`, which is absolutely wrong.

Even in W3Schools, the link you provided, they have it right:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So let's change your HTML to:

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="main.html">
        <img src="Images/Navigation/Full Intak Logo-01.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="printing">
      Printing
      <ul>
        <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
        <li>Banners</li>
        <li>A-Frame</li>
        <li>Menu Boards</li>
        <li>Takeout Menus</li>
        <li>Business Cards</li>
        <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
        <li>Posters</li>
        <li>Books</li>
        <li>Envelopes</li>
        <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Brochures</li>
        <li>Vinyl</li>
        <li>NCR Forms</li>
        <li>Catalogues</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">Graphic Design</li>
    <li class="item">Chinese Calendars</li>
    <li class="item">FAQS</li>
    <li class="item">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Now, we need to get the `<ul>` inside the `<li>` to display when you hover over the `<li>`. We can do it with CSS this way:

```css
li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

But the problem you face is bad, as the `<ul>` is not correctly aligned to it. For this, you need `position`ing.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

This works fine, but there's a problem of the `overflow` issue caused by `overflow: hidden`. Let's get that sorted now by removing it from the `nav`. The only thing left is to position the `<ul>` menu right way.

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

**Working Demo**

Now you get an awesome CSS menu. To be fair, you don't need the rest of the code, but I have not removed it. Hope this is alright. Here's your final snippet:

```css
* {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* vertical alignement */
  align-items: center;
  /* how you want horizontal distribution */
  /* space-evenly | space-around | space-between */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.printing {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2F4F4F;
}

.printing>li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="main.html">
        <img src="Images/Navigation/Full Intak Logo-01.png" alt="Home" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="printing">
      Printing
      <ul>
        <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
        <li>Banners</li>
        <li>A-Frame</li>
        <li>Menu Boards</li>
        <li>Takeout Menus</li>
        <li>Business Cards</li>
        <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
        <li>Posters</li>
        <li>Books</li>
        <li>Envelopes</li>
        <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
        <li>Flyers</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Brochures</li>
        <li>Vinyl</li>
        <li>NCR Forms</li>
        <li>Catalogues</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">Graphic Design</li>
    <li class="item">Chinese Calendars</li>
    <li class="item">FAQS</li>
    <li class="item">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: The problem I find when i run your code snippet is as soon as you move the mouse down to the drop down list, the menu disappears

Comment: @Yabusa Change `margin: 20px 0 0;` to `margin: 0;` and `padding: 25px;` to `padding: 45px 25px 25px;` That should work it as when you put a margin, the element isn't present there. We should use padding.