# Having difficulty hiding navigation sub menu even with display: none;

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The submenu I've created is always displaying in the navigation, even when I have `display: none;`. I'm not sure what in my code is not working

I was helped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379637/stuck-creating-nested-drop-down-navigation-menu/55379915?noredirect=1#comment97545505_55379915) to create the nested list. The code everyone provided worked, but I literally copied the code into my markup and it doesn't work. I need help spotting the error.

```
<style>

    * {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
        box-sizing: border-box;}

    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 25px 0;
        flex-direction: row;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .item {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .submenu {
        display: none;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #2F4F4F;
        color: white;
    }

    .item.has-children:hover .sub-menu {
        display: block;
        color: #2F4F4F;
    }


    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .flex-container > div {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

</style>
</head>
```

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item">
            <a href="main.html">
                <img src="Images/Navigation/Intak Logo 25px High.png" alt="Home" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">Printing
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Labels & Stickers</li>
                <li>Banners</li>
                <li>A-Frame</li>
                <li>Menu Boards</li>
                <li>Takeout Menus</li>
                <li>Business Cards</li>
                <li>Dine-In Menus</li>
                <li>Posters</li>
                <li>Envelopes</li>
                <li>Chinese Wedding Cards</li>
                <li>Flyers</li>
                <li>Letterheads</li>
                <li>Brochures</li>
                <li>Vinyl</li>
                <li>NCR Forms</li>
                <li>Catalogues</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">Graphic Design</li>
        <li class="item">Chinese Calendars</li>
        <li class="item">FAQS</li>
        <li class="item">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<body>

    <div class="flex-container">

    <div><img src="Images/Printing/Dinner Menus-01.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Banners" /></div>
    <div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Posters" /></div>
    <div><img src="Images/Printing/Banner.jpg" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" alt="Poster" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm expecting the navigation to drop a submenu under printing. I want to set it up in a row format. But I assume I'd just add flex-direction:row; after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your css (or html, depends on which is leading). In the html you have a `class="sub-menu"` but in your css you are refering to `.submenu`